# Conditionally change object class Java

Tags: java, class

So I have an existing piece of code that looks like this:

```
Metrics metrics = null;

try {
    metrics = metricsService.getCurrentMetrics();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//Do some stuff with the metrics
```

I have recently implemented a seperate mechanism as a way to track API metrics under a separate class, cleverly called APIMetrics.

So, with this change, the code would look something like this:

```
Metrics metrics = null;
APIMetrics apiMetrics = null;

try {
    if(user.isAPI())
        apiMetrics = metricsService.getCurrentAPIMetrics();

    else
        metrics = metricsService.getCurrentMetrics();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//Do some stuff with the metrics
```

The issue is that the code below, the "do some stuff with the metrics" is all written in terms of using the metrics object. Is there a way I can possibly set this up so that the "metrics" object refers not to just the object of type Metrics, but whatever object is the one we want to use?

So, for example, if we have a non-API user, we would want metrics to be of type Metrics and the result of metricsService.getCurrentMetrics(). However, if we have an API user, we would want metrics to be of type APIMetrics and the result of metricsService.getCurrentAPIMetrics().

Is there any good way to go about this? The Metrics and APIMetrics class share all methods. I know there may be a way to do this using inheritance or polymorphism, but I couldn't figure out exactly what to do. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you hit the nail on he head... inheritance (or interfacing, more specifically) would be a great solution here, what couldn't you figure out how to do?

Comment: I think it's mostly a matter of me wrapping my head around what that would change throughout the code base.

Comment: That's pretty vague. I suggest you read up on some tutorials about how to implement interfacing/inheritance and give it a try.

Comment: You don't need to change much.  Instead of having a `Metrics metrics` object, you'd have a `IMetrics metrics`.  Then you'd assign to the metrics variable as you already are and shouldn't have to change much if any of your code

Comment: Think of it it like this.  You can do ` List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`  Your list variable doesn't care if it's an ArrayList or any other type of list.  Your code will only be using stuff that can be found in the `List` interface, so you shouldn't have to change your code.

Answer (score 5):

Make both classes `Metrics` and `APIMetrics` implement the same interface. Then, declare a single variable whose type will be this interface, initialize it accordingly and use it through the code.

Comment: Thanks, I realize now this was actually a pretty dumb question. I knew the answer, just had trouble wrapping my head around how it would affect the code base.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as per the above answer you can make both classes implement an interface which declares all the methods.

```
public interface MetricsInt(){
// declare common methods
```

}

And in your code you can introduce a factory method that will take the user as an input and return the expected type of Metrics instance. Since the variable is of the type MetricInt, both type of objects can be set to it.

```
MetricsInt metrics = null;

try {
    metrics = metricsService.getCurrentMetricsForUser(user);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```